# Can I sprintf to an ArrayList in Zig?

Tags: arraylist, memory-management, format, zig

The Zig standard library contains the function `std.fmt.allocPrint` which takes in an allocator, prints to a buffer allocated with said allocator, and returns the result, much like a dynamic `sprintf`.

For my particular use-case, I need to concatenate multiple strings together after having printed to them. The only solution that I see, using `allocPrint`, is to first print to some allocated memory and then copy the bytes over to an `ArrayList`, which seems redundant.

Ideally, the standard library would include a function that allows one to print directly to an `ArrayList`, like the following:

```rust
pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    defer std.debug.assert(gpa.deinit() == .ok);
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();

    var list = std.ArrayList(u8).init(allocator);
    defer list.deinit();

    const values = [_]f64{ 5.6, 123.4, 19.6, 18.4 };

    for (values) |value| {
        try std.fmt.allocPrintToArrayList(list, "{e} ", .{value}); // Does not work
    }

    _ = list.pop();

    // Ideally `list.items` would include the `values` delimited by spaces
}
```

Is there a way of doing what I need in Zig? For example, maybe I could use `ArrayList` as an allocator so it can be, in turn, used with the `allocPrint` API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Printing to a Single String

I misunderstood the problem statement at first: I thought that OP wanted to collect strings in an `ArrayList`, but it seems that OP wants to create a single string by printing values followed by delimiters. The original solution is at the end of this answer.

`ArrayList` has a `writer` method which appends to the end of a list. You can combine that with a bit of logic to print delimiters to arrive at the desired result.

```
const std = @import("std");
const allocPrint = std.fmt.allocPrint;
const append = std.ArrayList.append;

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();
    defer std.debug.assert(gpa.deinit() == .ok);

    var list = std.ArrayList(u8).init(allocator);
    defer list.deinit();

    const values = [_]f64{ 5.6, 123.4, 19.6, 18.4 };

    const delimiter = " ";
    for (values, 1..) |value, i| {
        try list.writer().print(
            "{e}{s}",
            .{ value, if (i < values.len) delimiter else "" },
        );
    }

    std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{list.items});
}
```

```
> .\arraylist_string
5.6e+00 1.234e+02 1.96e+01 1.84e+01
```

### The Original Answer: Creating a List of Strings

You can use `ArrayList.append` to append the result of calling `allocPrint` to the `ArrayList` since `allocPrint` returns a slice of the bytes which were printed. Since `allocPrint` makes an allocation each time it is called these will also need to be freed.

The `ArrayList` will also need to hold `[]u8` types instead of `u8` types.

```
const std = @import("std");
const allocPrint = std.fmt.allocPrint;
const append = std.ArrayList.append;

pub fn main() !void {
    var gpa = std.heap.GeneralPurposeAllocator(.{}){};
    const allocator = gpa.allocator();
    defer std.debug.assert(gpa.deinit() == .ok);

    var list = std.ArrayList([]u8).init(allocator);
    defer list.deinit();

    const values = [_]f64{ 5.6, 123.4, 19.6, 18.4 };

    for (values) |value| {
        try list.append(
            try (allocPrint(allocator, "{e} ", .{value})),
        );
    }
    // free strings created by `allocPrint`
    defer {
        for (list.items) |s| {
            allocator.free(s);
        }
    }

    for (list.items) |s| {
        std.debug.print("{s}\n", .{s});
    }
}
```

```
> .\arraylist_strings
5.6e+00
1.234e+02
1.96e+01
1.84e+01
```